# Is it possible to get the data type of mongodb collection fields using c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, datatable

I need to create a datatable that stores the result of mongodb query using the correct data type of the fields (String ,double...). here is the code I am using but here I am specifying the type of the created column as a string type I need to find a way to get the correct type of the field:

```
        var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var database = server.GetDatabase("test");
        var collection = database.GetCollection("doc1"); 
        DataTable dt;
        DataColumn Column;
        int i = 0;

        dt = new DataTable();
        string map = @"function() { 
   for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
   }";
        string reduce = @"function(key, stuff) { return null; }";
        string finalize = @"function(key, value){
       return key;
   }";
        MapReduceArgs args = new MapReduceArgs();
        args.FinalizeFunction = new BsonJavaScript(finalize);
        args.MapFunction = new BsonJavaScript(map);
        args.ReduceFunction = new BsonJavaScript(reduce);
        var results = collection.MapReduce(args);
        List<string> fields = new List<string>();
        foreach (BsonValue result in results.GetResults().Select(item => item["_id"]))
        {
            fields.Add(result.AsString);
        }


        foreach (string p in fields)
        {// here I need to add the correct type of the field not string type
            Column = new DataColumn(p, Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt.Columns.Add(Column);
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: not sure exactly what you're asking for here.  do you have a code sample that isn't working?

Comment: The MongoDB Bson serializer for C# stores the type of the object in a field in each document in a collection. Read the documentation on serialization.

Comment: I added my code but it's not giving me the result I need. I have just started with mongodb thus I read the documentation but I couldn't  find how to get the type of the fields of my collection I would appreciate if you could provide me with a sample code so that I can get something like this : input mongodb collection {"name" : "nn", "number": 3} output datatable  (column :name :String / colmn :number: double)